# Calling Reporting Services Web Service from SharePoint using Kerberos over SSL

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008, ssl, kerberos

I have multiple SharePoint web parts that needs to access Reporting service 2008 which is integrated into MOSS2007.

There are 2 end points that I will be using: ReportService2006 and ReportExecution2005.

I would like to put all the logic that calls the web service in one common assembly (class library) which will be packaged within the same WSP that contains the web parts.

I attempted to add a service reference from my common class library project but the proxy is not generated properly and I cannot use any intellisense at design time. Therefore I am now using svcutil.exe to generate the proxies.

Unfortunately Microsoft said that svcutil.exe would have problems with Kerberos authentication in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx):

> Svcutil.exe generates the client based
>   on the Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL) or policy file
>   received from the service. The user
>   principal name (UPN) is generated by
>   concatenating the user name with "@"
>   and then adding a fully-qualified
>   domain name (FQDN). However, for users
>   who registered on Active Directory,
>   this format is not valid and the UPN
>   that the tool generates causes a
>   failure in the Kerberos authentication
>   with the following error message: The
>   logon attempt failed. To resolve this
>   problem, manually fix the client file
>   that the tool generated

My environment has been set up to use Kerberos over SSL. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No replies for this thread, so I used asmx instead of WCF and it now works like a charm....